# mod_rewrite links to css/javascript still being messed up after %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am truly trying to accomplish the most simple thing...

Redirect:  http_://somehost/.../site_directory/Arg1/Arg2

To: http_://somehost/.../site_directory/index.php?a=Arg1&b=Arg2

I've set up mod_rewrite like so (in a .htaccess file in /site_directory)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC]
```

I'm getting all kinds of errors because my javascript and css files are being searched for in /site_directory/Arg1/Arg2.

What on earth stupid thing am I doing to screw this up? Thanks in advance.

(mod_rewrite is installed and working because index.php spits back the $_GET arguments as I tell it to and they are 'Arg1' and 'Arg2')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference your scripts and CSS files with an absolute path instead of a relative.

```
<script src="/site_directory/foobar.js">
```

instead of

```
<script src="foobar.js">
```

So the file will be loaded from `/site_directory/foobar.js`, not from `/site_directory/Arg1/Arg2/foobar.js`.